# How to apply a formula to an excel 2d range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

This is probably not so complicated problem but I could not seem to wrap my head around it.

There is an excel range like:

[image]

Now the goal is to use the formula =(cellValue/2)*50 to each cell in the range. The output looks like:

[image]

Of course it can be done row by row or column by column. But is there any easier way to do it considering that there can be more subjects and even large number of students?

Here is my code and I am using excel 2016:

```
int lastRow = wsht.Cells.Find("*", Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Row;
int lastCol = wsht.Cells.Find("*", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Column;

            int i=2;
            for(i=2;i<=lastCol;i++)
            {
                string colName = getColumnName(i);
                wsht.Cells[2, (lastCol+1)].Formula = "=(" + colName + "2/2)*50";
                wsht.Cells[2, (lastCol+1)].AutoFill(wsht.Range[wsht.Cells[2, (lastCol+1)], wsht.Cells[lastRow, (lastCol+1)]], XlAutoFillType.xlFillValues);

                wsht.Range[wsht.Cells[2, (lastCol+1)], wsht.Cells[lastRow, (lastCol+1)]].Copy();
                wsht.Range[wsht.Cells[2, i], wsht.Cells[lastRow, i]].PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
```

With larger number of rows and columns, above code will take time. The pastespecial options are add, subtract, multiply and divide. How to apply little more complicated formula in this case?

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you divide by 2 and then multiply by 50? It makes more sense to simply multiply by 25.

Comment: This is just for example which is not a simple addition or subtraction. It can be any mathematical formula. Well, I couldn't think of any better one!

Comment: **a)** Select an area the same size as your source, eg. `F2:H6`; **b)** type the formula `=(B2:D6/2)*50` and **c)** hit Control+Shift+Enter to confirm the array-formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by formula. Try below formula.

```
=(INDEX($B$2:$D$6,ROW($A1),COLUMN(A$1))/2)*50
```

[image]

If you want to do it by `VBA` codes then try below sub-

```
Sub Multiply50()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = sh.Cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each rng In sh.Range("B2:" & Cells(lRow, lCol).Address)
        rng = (rng / 2) * 50
    Next

Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```